# Cannot Input Login Credentials Using Selenium

Tags: python

I am having such a hard time typing my login credentials into this form on a website using selenium. I have worked with selenium a ton of times and never had issues with send_keys not actually typing anything. I am certain I'm using the correct xpath.

website:

https://causewayclub.tennisbookings.com/LoginX.aspx

My code is as follows:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,
                                   executable_path=r'\\computerpath\\c$\\test\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe')

browser.get('https://causewayclub.tennisbookings.com/LoginX.aspx')

element = browser.findElement(By.XPATH('//*[@id="txtUsername"]')).send_keys("TEST")
        element.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '9.00')", element)

        password = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="txtPassword"]')))\
            .send_keys('Password')
        login_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btnLogin"]'))).click()
```

Comment: What issue are you seeing? Do you get an error or are you not seeing the results that you're expecting?

Comment: @hangonstack2 the cursor just blinks on the username. The string “test” does not appear on the username text box. Its like if thats not the xpath or something. It will time out because of my webdriver wait function.

Comment: Do you need to add a wait between `browser.get` and `browser.findElement`? I have a similar script for login and I needed to add a `WebDriverWait`, similar to what you have after `element.executeScript`

In my script I also do `send_keys(Keys.TAB)` after entering the strings that I want. Some Javascript driven UI might need that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, by the way I removed the chrome driver path you might have to add it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get('https://causewayclub.tennisbookings.com/LoginX.aspx')

element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='txtUsername']").send_keys("TEST")

password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='txtPassword']").send_keys("Password")

login_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnLogin"]').click()
```

Edit: It might be because of the page haven't loaded yet, so the element is unavailable. Try adding a `time.sleep(10)`(`import time` in the beginning) after `browser.get('https://causewayclub.tennisbookings.com/LoginX.aspx')`

OR there is another way, check this documentation.
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: i get selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='txtUsername']"}
i have tried this way also. I looked at the HTML and did inspect and I see a ton of javascript and divs on top of divs. Wonder if they are trying to mask it so no one uses a script?

Comment: I ran it, it worked for me. so they are not trying to block a script. I added some more to the answer try that